# Draging and object from child view and placing it in parent view

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, gesture

I'm trying to implement dragging objects from child view and placing them in parent view. For example, I have a container UIView and it has some buttons in it and also have another view inside container view with some images. What I'm trying to do is dragging an image from child view and place it on container UIView. I'm using pan gestures in both of the views but it doesn't give me the result that I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have created something similar in the past using delegation. Have the parent to be the delegate of the child view, create a method that keeps track of and object and it’s location and the when the pan has ended, create a copy of the object and add it as a subview within your parent view and then remove the original object from the super view.

Issue you might face: 
-when an object  is dragged within the child view its location will be the location from the child’s views bounds , so you need to create a method do retrieve the location of the object from the parents views coordinates.

- make sure the child’s view view clips to bounds is set to false.

I hope this sets you in the right direction.

Comment: It is not working smoothly now I'm trying to implement with another approach thanks for the suggestion.